# I Would Like To Use Bootstrap 2 in my Action Mailer View

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, actionmailer

I currently use Bootstrap 2 in my Rails 4.0.13 application. I am using a table to simulate two columns with the width parameter.

```
<table style="width: 800px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 33%; padding: 10px;" valign="top" align="justify"><%= @mass_email_parm["email"].html_email_left.html_safe %></td>
    <td style="width: 67%; padding: 10px;" valign="top" align="justify"><%= @mass_email_parm["email"].html_email_text.html_safe %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have this in my  tag in my mailer view.

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

I would like to rewrite my logic using span4 and span8 or something like that if possible. I have tried several times to see if there is a way to use Bootstrap in the mailer but have not found anything.

I thought I might try something like adding the link statement below. However I wonder about the meta statement I have. I have not worked with either of these much regarding mailer views.

```
<link href="assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, many (probably most) email providers strip out external stylesheet links.  Gmail and others even strip embedded CSS, meaning your only real option is inline styling.  My advice is to either inline style, or use a tool that will convert CSS to inline styles.  See [this excellent article](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1) for more details.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks. I may change using the table for a div.

Comment: @LightBeCorp HTML for emails is a completely different ball game than regular HTML and CSS for websites. The industry standard for emails is to use tables since there's no fail-safe way to apply css styles to email markup. You might want to take a look at this article about Email Coding Guidelines from Campaign Monitor: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/coding/guidelines/

Comment: @JeanLescure after I posted my comment I decided to leave the table in my mailer for now and work on a marketing project. Guess I was doing the standard without realizing it. This link also answered some other questions regarding images in emails. I may remove them from my mailers since some people may not see them without clicking it first.